# Google Play Billing 2.0: How to trigger pending transactions

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-billing, play-billing-library

I implemented Google Play Billing Library 2.0 recently, but I cannot successfully trigger the pending transaction. when I opened Google Play purchase dialog, I don't have an option like "GET PAYMENT CODE" button, instead, just a normal purchase dialog with "BUY" button

**Expected result:** 
[image: Expected purchase dialog]

**Actual result:** 
[image: Acutal purchase dialog]

And I also followed the [guideline](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#test_pending_transactions_with_license_testers):

> Pending transactions can be tested using license testers. In addition to two test credit cards, license testers have access to two test instruments for delayed forms of payment which automatically complete or cancel after a couple of minutes.

Which added "License Testing" account in Google Play console (setting -> Developer account-> account details-> License Testing), but it still not works. So how can I test the pending transaction purchase flow?

Comment: Just click on "Test card, always approves". There will be an option "Slow test card. Approves after a few minutes". After few minutes you receive an email with a payment, which mean that now your purchase is confirmed and when a user launches your app, you should give him the purchased item